# I can't save instance of fragment to not restart after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, screen-orientation, savestate

My fragment's code looks like this:

```
public class AllIssuesFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.list_all_issues) ListView mListAllIssues;
IssuesGetter ai;
ArrayAdapter<IssuesResponse.Issue> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_issues, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    SharedPreferences user_data = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    UserManager.getInstance().setUsername(user_data.getString("username", null));
    UserManager.getInstance().setPassword(user_data.getString("password", null));

    if(UserManager.getInstance().getUsername() == null || UserManager.getInstance().getPassword() == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChangeUserActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getIssues(Constants.URI + Constants.ISSUES + Constants.OFFSET + 0);
        }
        mListAllIssues.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {
                boolean loadMore = firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

                if (loadMore && ai.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                    getIssues(Constants.URI + Constants.ISSUES + Constants.OFFSET + totalCount);
                    mListAllIssues.setSelection(totalCount);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void getIssues(String url) {
    ai = new IssuesGetter(new AsyncCallback<IssuesResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IssuesResponse response) {
            int index = mListAllIssues.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = mListAllIssues.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (v == null)? 0 : v.getTop();

            adapter.addAll(response.getIssues());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListAllIssues.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListAllIssues.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChangeUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ai.execute(url);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Bind(R.id.viewpager) ViewPager viewPager;
@Bind(R.id.tabs) PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainActivityPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    tabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_change_user) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangeUserActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I've tried to use *setRetainInstance(true)* and check if the ***savedInstanceState equals null***, but it didn't solve my problem. I am stuck :(

My Asynctask returns result using call back.

Comment: Can you show code of the activity that uses this fragment?

Comment: `private ArrayList<IssuesResponse.Issue> cache;` then ... in `getIssues` ... if `cache` != null then set adapter from it ... if is null execute asynctask and set `cache` from response.getIssues() and set adapter ... the point is that fragment's retaining no working with UI components ... **edit** seems like you are using paging ... then it will not be so easy ...

Comment: @Nolane, I added it.

Comment: @Selvin, yes, I am using paging. And I am newbie, so it is hard for me to implement this feature.

Comment: @VitalyRomaniv I wanted to see the code of Activity class.

Comment: @Nolane, sorry. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here:

```
public void onCreate() {
    //..
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainActivityPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    tabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

This method is called each time activity is recreated. And what it does is creates new adapter which creates brand new fragments. And that is a problem. Because your activity doesn't control creation of fragments. That is neccessary in order to retain fragments.

I suggest you to save state of fragment in onSaveInstanceState() callback and restore it in onCreateView(). Note that you don't need to save state of UI elements just variables of fragment class. UI elements save their state automatically if they have unique id.

EDIT:

My suggestion:

```
public class AllIssuesFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<String> issues;
    // ..

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ..
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            issues = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("issues");
        } else {
            issues = new List<>();
        }
        adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, issues);
        // ..
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArray("issues", issues);
    }

    private void getIssues(String url) {
        // ..
        ai = new IssuesGetter(new AsyncCallback<IssuesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IssuesResponse response) {
                // ..
                //adapter.addAll(response.getIssues());
                issues.addAll(response.getIssues());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // ..
            }
        };
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me in detail how can I do it?

Comment: @VitalyRomaniv, it's hard to talk about details without diving into the code.

Comment: ok. I should override onSaveInstanceState in AllIssuesFragment? But how can I save state of fragment there?